# read a huge amount of data

Tags: java, eclipse, urlconnection

In a java program (Eclipse ISE on a PC) I want to read a huge amount of data (around 1640188 bytes) from a web site. With Wireshark I can see that these datas come in many blocks of 1460 bytes.
When I use the following code I read only the first block seen at high level (size around 18000 bytes). How could I do to have the other blocks?

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream input = con.getInputStream();
while(input.available()>0)
{
        System.out.println(input.available());
        int n = input.available();
        byte[] mydataTab = new byte[n];
        input.read(mydataTab, 0, n);
        String str = new String(mydataTab);
        memoData += str;
}
```

Comment: Huge amount?  Isn't that only 1.5 megabytes?

Comment: Check this link. https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-url-read-contents-httpurl-connection-java

Comment: Why are you concerned with reading larger byte counts each time? If you're trying to make things faster or more efficient, you could stop creating new strings – `new String(mydataTab)` and `memoData += str` both create new objects – and instead use a single byte array that you add repeatedly add to. Take a look at [this other signature for `read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)).

Comment: kaan: If I use a single byte array, server read lasts many minutes.

Comment: thnaks a lot Sambit. It seems to work despite the site use no endLine caracter

Comment: Don't use `available`.  That is not what it is intended for.  (Read the javadoc.  Carefully!)

Answer (score 3):

First:
Do not

`int n = input.available();
byte[] mydataTab = new byte[n];`

because:

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer
>   intended to hold all data in this stream.

[Java InputStream Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available())

Second:
Try to use some predefined chunck size for your reading, so you can do:

```
int chuncksize = 1024;
int sizeRead = input.read(mydataTab, 0, n);
```

where the `sizeRead` is the amount of bytes that you read.
And keep reading the chunks until the end of the streaming.